# How to read an int from OutputStreamWriter?

Tags: android, int, storage

I have tried searching online to find a solution or some way that I can learn how to read the integer, but alas I have come here to see if any of you guys can help me.

Please & Thank you

```
public void writetofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("intvalue.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(Counter);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}

public int readfromfile() {
    int Counter = 0;

    return Counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now read this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm

From what is see i recommend Shared preferences:
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

And learning java programming once and not searching little by little saves a lot of time. there are some good free eBooks: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/